# How to use snackBar in Angular 2

Tags: angular-material2

I use sanckbar but its position is not on bottom

[image]

what could be the issue ?

git https://github.com/ashjha/snakebar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When no code is provided, it's hard to check what's wrong.
However, I'm using the MdSnackBar (still in development), and it's working for me.

First off, the "snackbar component" itself must be included, as well as  "MdSnackBarConfig" using:

```
import { MdSnackBar, MdSnackBarConfig } from '@angular/material';
import { ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
```

After this, we can create or initialize the snackbar item and our viewContainerRef in the constructor:

```
 constructor(
    private snackbar: MdSnackBar,
    public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
  ) { }
```

Now we can call the snackbar to be showed whenever we want, using:

```
   let config = new MdSnackBarConfig(this.viewContainerRef);
   this.snackbar.open('Snackbar text', 'Ok', config);
```

Please see the github for more info and updates, since this is an initial version.

Hope this helps somewhat

Comment: [ts] Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target. at this line new MdSnackBarConfig(this.viewContainerRef);

Comment: I quickly created this blank plunker from the official Angular 2 material plunker.

Comment: Thanx for your help , but i am getting same issue , i have changed open function open() {
     let config = new MdSnackBarConfig();
      config.duration = this.autoHide;
      config.viewContainerRef = this.viewContainerRef;
    this.snackbar.open('This is a snackbar ', 'Ok', config);
  }
now snackbar is showing but not on bottom

Comment: I copy/pasted your config into the plunker, and it still works.
It may be that I don't really know what you are trying to do. Could you create a plunker, paste code or screenshot so I have a better understanding? 
Also, make sure that you're using the "correct" version of the material 2 library.
[link](http://plnkr.co/edit/hSYVUwaeuZa141Kmk1Wq?p=preview)

Comment: post updated plz check , git link is https://github.com/ashjha/snakebar

Comment: i am using latest version of CLI so i need to import theaming in style.css , now it is fix

Comment: Just wanted you guys to know i updated the plunkr to a more recent version of Angular 2... http://plnkr.co/edit/tQfo0NgiK0XcmRoIVWhr?p=preview

Comment: @ChristianMatthew Thank you for keeping this up-to-date! :)

Answer (score 2):

**Hope this will help you All :**

```
import { MdSnackBar } from '@angular/material';
export class DemoStackOverflow{
    constructor(
        private snackBar: MdSnackBar
    ){}

    showSnackBar(){
        this.snackBar.open("Yes i am Coming", "Ok", {
            duration: 9000
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing a ViewContainerRef to config will limit the snackbar to the same. You should pass `config.viewContainerRef = null`. This will place the snackBar to the center of the page.